# For a travelling object, does the rest of the universe will have relativistic mass?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, mass, observers

We know everything is stationary in its frame of reference no matter how much speed it has. Yet if the object is moving with relativistic speed; in its frame of reference the whole universe is moving in the opposite direction with the same speed.
Does this mean the whole universe is gaining relativistic mass?

Comment: Relativistic mass is an obsolete notion that is no longer in use (although its definition is fine, mathematically speaking). You're better off forgetting about it. Only the (invariant) mass is useful.

Comment: Your first statement doesn't hold true for photons or any massless particles, there is no frame of reference in which they are stationary.

Comment: You can only be moving at relativistic speed relative to some other reference frame.  It's all also more complex in general relativity which is what you need to deal with things on a cosmological scale.

Comment: useful link  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/tdil.html#c3

Comment: Thank you all!......